# ITMS-90171 When Archiving Caused by MLModel Files

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, mlmodel

I'm trying to submit an app to the store that contains a bundle of `.mlmodel` files.

When I archive the app and upload it to the app store I get a list of errors, one for each `.mlmodel` file that is in the bundle.

An example of such an error is:

> "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file
>   'MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/AIModels.bundle/bot2emb51.o'
>   is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or
>   libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles.
>   Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at
>   https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on
>   the iOS app bundle structure."

In this particular case I have a file that's marked for inclusion in the `AIModels` bundle called `bot2emb51.mlmodel`. I'm not sure why the file is being compiled into an object file, I thought it would be copied as an `mlmodel` file.

Are there any Xcode settings I need to change, or flags that I can set in the compiled to work around this?